# How to download dvd covers from https://www.dvdempire.com/all-movie.html

Tags: ssl, download, jpeg, wget

Hello stackoverflow community. I am asking for help with downloading dvd covers from a dvd shop website (dvdempire.com). I am using wget for Windows.

So the syntax would be wget -r -A .jpg https://www.dvdempire.com/all-movies.html

But the problem is that it doesnt want to connect with SSL. The handshake fails.

Maybe the website has disabled mass downloading of DVD covers because of bandwidth or copyright reasons ?

The covers can be manually downloaded by clicking each link, but it would be much faster to do it with a batch program.

There are some 115000 covers in total.

Answer (score 1):

The [Terms of Use](https://www.dvdempire.com/help/cs_termsofuse.html) page for the site includes the following:

> "Read these terms carefully before you ("You") accept these Terms by: (a) placing an order through DVDEmpire or (b) otherwise using the Websites."
>
> "You agree, further, not to use or attempt to use any engine, software, tool, agent or other device or mechanism (including without limitation browsers, spiders, robots, avatars or intelligent agents) to navigate or search the Websites other than the search engine and search agents available from DVDEmpire on the Websites and other than generally available third party web browsers (e.g., Netscape Navigator, Microsoft Explorer)."

I suggest that you contact the site maintainers directly about what you want to do.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will rethink, maybe I will manually download just the covers that I would like to have. The thread can now be closed.